# C++ callback - issue when used with Python

Tags: python, c++, callback

A have a program with following design:

```
class Callback {
    void log(std::string text) {
        (...)
    }
}

class Processing {
    void setCallback(Callback* c) {
        cb = c;
    }

    void run() {
        (...)
        if (cb)
            cb.log("text");
        (...)
    }
    Callback* cb;
}
```

I'm creating Processing object and Callback object. Processing::run methon runs in loop and from time to time executes Callback::log method from object set in Processing::setCallback method. This works fine:

```
int main() {
    Callback cb;
    Processing pp;
    pp.setCallback(&cb);
    pp.run;
}
```

Now I exported those classes and created Python module using Boost::Python to run this code from Python. This also works fine:

```
callback = module.Callback()
processing = module.Processing()
processing.setCallback(callback)
processing.run()
```

Problem occures when I want to create more than one Processing object:

```
callbacks = []
processings = []
for i in range (3)
    callbacks.append(module.Callback())
    processings.append(module.Processing())
    processings[i].setCallback(callbacks[i])
    processings[i].run()
```

I get crash and segmentation fault when second Processing object calls Callback::log method. I checked and all Callback and Processing objects seems to be properly created and have different addresses.
Analogical example (many objects) but written i C++ works ok.

Any idea what may be the issue?

Comment: Have you initialized pyGil in your C++ code. I think pyGil needs to be initialized.I have faced similar issue but i am not sure exactly same. You can initialize pyGil by using Py_Initialize(); and PyEval_InitThreads();

Comment: I did. It didn't help.